# Identify Store App Type

Tags: windows-phone-8, uwp, windows-store-apps

From Microsoft Store if we select an app to install, how to identify whether the app is built on win 8/8.1/10?

Like how to know from seeing the app in store whether it is a metro app or UWP app?

Comment: Generally speaking, no, we cannot know where the app is built. Any reason about why you need to do this? Store will choose the right type of the package you provided to your customer. And in UWP technology we don't recommend you think about detect the device type. If you have a speicific API you need to use  Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation to help you understnad whether you can use that API. Anyway, please provide us more details about why you need to do this first. It would help us understand your requirement.

Comment: We want to understand current market trend like which applications are consumed by users more generally and propose the same to our Planning Team, as we are going to suggest some approaches.
So can I know how it can be identified?

Comment: As for every app there is a sys requirements details. So if it is mentioned "win 8 or higher" can't we identify that as a win8 metro app and if they mention "win 10.0.14393 or higher" can't we identify the type as uwp app? Is this conclusion incorrect? Kindly help

Comment: Nope. We cannot identify the type from dashboard and also from app API level. And if you have a windows 8 package and a UWP package, actually on windows 10 the UWP package will be installed.